# Java: How to add a string value in a custom ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to know how can I add a string value in a custom ArrayList.

I have tried the below code but it gives me error

```
ArrayList<MyCustom> aList = new ArrayList<MyCustom>();

aList.add("My Name");
```

and tried this too;

```
aList.addAll("My Name");

aList.add((MyCustom)"My Name");
```

Comment: `String` doesn't extend `MyCustom`, so you use `String` in place of `MyCustom`. By the way, I'm pretty sure, that `MyCustom` also not extends `String` as `String` is final.

Comment: @Dmitry Ginzburg any alternative for this?

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve. For example, you can use `ArrayList<Object>` or (if only `String`s would be contained) you should use `ArrayList<String>`

Comment: I need to add one string somewhere in ArrayList.

Comment: `ArrayList <Object>` allows adding `String`s as `String` IS-A `Object`.

Answer (score 2):

suppose your class `MyCustom` and  have property say `name`:

```
class MyCustom{
     String name;
     public setName(String name){
        this.name=name;
     }
     .....
   }

ArrayList<MyCustom> aList = new ArrayList<MyCustom>();
MyCustom myCustomObject=new MyCustom();
myCustomObject.setName("abc"); // here set the properties for your custom class object
aList.add(myCustomObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created a list that will contains objects of type `MyCustom` so you can't add String to it unless your object extends String.

If you want a list that will contains String and MyCustom objects so you have to create your list like this :

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
list.add(new MyCustom(...));
list.add("Some String");
```

Comment: Using raw types is bad and would most likely be prohibited by Java if it weren't for backwards compatibility. Use `List<Object>` and `ArrayList<Object>` instead of `List` and `ArrayList`

Comment: @KuluLimpa I'm aware of that I just forgot when I typed the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned earlier, your "MyCustom" is neither a child nor a parent of String (and it cannot be either).
This would bring us to the need of your "MyCustom" object or what you want it to do/perform.

By using the below code, you are restricted the object types in the List to Mycustom, which is good. But if you HAVE to add a String in that list then you should remove the types. Also using the List interface is a better practice.

```
ArrayList<MyCustom> aList = new ArrayList<MyCustom>();
List aList = new ArrayList(); //This will allow all objects to be added to list.
```

Or depending on your need for MyCustom object you can modify it to be used as below:
`aList.add(new MyCustom("Name String"));` 
or 
    `aList.add(new MyCustom().setName("Name String"));`

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList in java is a generic type. means that it can store any object. but to store object in ArrayList we need to specify the class name that that means ArrayList only store the object tthat class name u have specified while declaring the array list.

in your case

```
ArrayList<MyCustom> aList = new ArrayList<MyCustom>();
```

you declare the array list that have only MyCustom class object but

```
aList.add("My Name");
```

You are storing the string value. and there is no relation between the String class and MyCustom class. so java compiler show the error. to achive this you need to implement either

```
ArrayList<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>();

aList.add("My Name");
```

or

```
Class MyCustom {

String field;

public void setField(String f) {

field=f;
}

public String getField() {

return field;
}

}
```

then

```
ArrayList<MyCustom> aList = new ArrayList<MyCustom>();

aList.add(new MyCustom().setField("My Name"));
```